# how to create thumbnail from image datatype with codeigniter and sql server 2005 database?

Tags: image, sql-server-2005, codeigniter, thumbnails

I'm developing web application using latest codeigniter framework and SQL Server 2005. In my database, i have a table that have a column wth image datatype. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630711/help-reading-binary-image-data-from-sql-server-into-php) I know how to retrieve that image with this :

```
$q = "Get_Picture_Test_SP @pk_rms_id=1443546";
$res = mssql_query($q);

$row = mssql_fetch_assoc($res);

$image = $row['picture'];

function hex2bin($h)
{
    if (!is_string($h)) return null;
    $r='';
    for ($a=0; $a<strlen($h); $a+=2) { $r.=chr(hexdec($h{$a}.$h{($a+1)})); }
    return $r;
 }

$image = hex2bin($image);
```

What i want to know is how can i make a thumbnail from that image to make the web loading more fast? If I use image from some path i know how to make the thumbnail (hope i not wrong) with this :

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']     = 75;
$config['height']   = 50;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

 $this->image_lib->resize();
```

I still dont know how to creating thumbnail from image data type. Hope anyone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');

$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']     = 75;
$config['height']   = 50;

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);

if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
{
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

In your code your forget to initialize the config..So please use this code make sure the image path is correct..Hopefully this will work.

Comment: oh yes, i forget to including that line in my question. But my problem is actually how to make thumbnail not from image that i load from a path, but from database. I already explained it in my question..

Comment: I know that you want to create thumbnails from the image which you have in db...You can create thumbnail of that image by just changing the source path in the config......